# Sort print() text in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have some python code to make telephone numbers vote on a country. They can not vote on their own and so on.. doesn't really matter

```
import random

Countries = ["Belgium", "Netherlands", "Italy", "France", "Germany", "Spain"]

for num in range(5):
    country = random.choice(Countries)

    if(country is "Belgium"):
        phone = f'+32 4{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[0, 25, 7, 25, 25, 7], k=1)

    elif(country is "Netherlands"):
        phone = f'+31 6{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[25, 0, 5, 15, 20, 8], k=1)

    elif(country is "Italy"):
        phone = f'+39 3{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[5, 5, 0, 20, 5, 13], k=1)

    elif(country is "France"):
        phone = f'+33 1{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[15, 8, 10, 0, 12, 8], k=1)

    elif(country is "Germany"):
        phone = f'+49 1{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[8, 8, 9, 5, 0, 12, 3], k=1)

    elif(country is "Spain"):
        phone = f'+34 6{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[5, 5, 15, 15, 10, 0], k=1)

    else:
        phone = f'Country does not exist'
        countryVote = random.choice(Countries)

    print(f'{phone} voted for {countryVote}')
```

My output looks like this

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtJZ5.jpg)

What I want to achieve is to sort the numbers, so all +31 numbers are grouped together for example. 
I only found how to sort a list of objects but not printed text..

```
lines = print.readlines() 
lines.sort()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a `list` outside of your loop, `append` each string to the list inside the loop, then print the `sorted` list.

Comment: Once you print it to stdout the data is beyond the control of your program.  Put the values in a list and sort the list before outputting.

Comment: (And don't use `is` for comparing strings.)

Answer (score 1):

For example you can collect phone numbers to the list before printing and then print resulting list with sort function:

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

Countries = ["Belgium", "Netherlands", "Italy", "France", "Germany", "Spain"]
result_numbers = []

for num in range(5):
    country = random.choice(Countries)

    if(country is "Belgium"):
        phone = f'+32 4{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[0, 25, 7, 25, 25, 7], k=1)

    elif(country is "Netherlands"):
        phone = f'+31 6{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[25, 0, 5, 15, 20, 8], k=1)

    elif(country is "Italy"):
        phone = f'+39 3{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[5, 5, 0, 20, 5, 13], k=1)

    elif(country is "France"):
        phone = f'+33 1{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[15, 8, 10, 0, 12, 8], k=1)

    elif(country is "Germany"):
        phone = f'+49 1{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[8, 8, 9, 5, 0, 12, 3], k=1)

    elif(country is "Spain"):
        phone = f'+34 6{random.randint(1000, 9999)}-{random.randint(1000,9999)}'
        countryVote = random.choices(Countries, weights=[5, 5, 15, 15, 10, 0], k=1)

    else:
        phone = f'Country does not exist'
        countryVote = random.choice(Countries)

    result_numbers.append(f'{phone} voted for {countryVote}')

pprint(sorted(result_numbers))
```

btw do not use `is` for comparing strings and one more:
Countries is not a class, so you need to user lowercase or uppercase if you want make it constant)